# Django Raw Query does not Output

Tags: django, django-views

views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    employee = Employee.objects.count()
    position1 = Posit.objects.raw('SELECT employee.stat, count(posit.position_id) as NO FROM employee, posit WHERE employee.id = posit.employee_id AND posit.position_id="1" GROUP BY employee.stat')
    
    context = {
        'employee ': employee ,
        'posit ': posit ,
        
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard.html', context)
```

I can output the employee count by using {{employee}} but when I use {{posit}} the position output is "RawQuerySet". This is the output in MariaDb using the raw query.

| employee.stat | NO |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 30 |

How can I output all the value of each employee.stat in the dashboard.html? Also can I output each employee.stat NO seperately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the RawQuerySet according to the documentation, so your code needs to be along these lines:

```
context = {
  'employee ': employee ,
  'posit': [pos for pos in position1]    
}
```

Then, you can iterate over the posit variable in a template tag such as:

```
{% for pos in posit %}
```

and then use `{{pos}}` when you need it.

Comment: It finally works. I got an Error about "Raw query must include a primary key", It can be fixed by adding the "employee.id" in the select statement. I got another Issue, I used the {{pos.NO}} it outputs all NO  100, 20, 10. How can I output the 1st part which is 100.

Comment: Does the output have a specific format to it, such as list or list of tuples?

Comment: I want to output it one by one like this in HTML.
Department 1 : {{pos.No}} Paragraph

Department 2 : {{pos.No}} Paragraph

Department 3 : {{pos.No}} Paragraph

Comment: You can do it with ```{{pos.NO.0}}``` and so on with 1 and 2.

Comment: I tried to use it a while ago, but it does not output anything.

Comment: Are you able to access the individual values with ```{{pos.employee.stat}}``` as an example?

Comment: Yes, I can access individual values.